# Change order of array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system), and the navigation is generated dynamically depending on what pages are in the "pages" directory. I then use scandir() to build the array of pages and a loop to build the navigation.

The problem is, I'd like to be able to change the order of the pages in the navigation by a user-defined #.

I.e., "Home - Contact us - About us" could be changed to "Home - About us - Contact us" depending on if the user set the "weight" of the "About us" page to a lower value.

```
<?php
    $views_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "kloudcms/" . VIEWS_LOCATION;
    $views = scandir($views_dir, 0);
    unset($views[0], $views[1]);

    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($views as $view) {
        $page_name = substr($view, 0, count($view) - 5);
        echo "<li>" . ucwords($page_name) . "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this problem?

Comment: We have plenty of other pages that demonstrate how to do a custom-sort with weight/priority defined in a lookup array.  We don't have a [mcve] here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a CMS, then I think it’s better to have a section for generating Static Pages with option to add weight for each page, save it in database, and query the pages sorting it according to weights assigned to it.

As per your current situation, since you are using scandir, you can only sorted alphabetically:

```
scandir(string $directory [, int $sorting_order = SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING [, resource $context]])
```

Reference: [Sorting Scandir listing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Comment: Ohhh, okay. I didn't know that. I'll give it a try that way and see what I get. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "classical" sort defined in PHP. Here is the list of the sort functions:

*[Sorting Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)*

But if you need a user-defined sort, you can check these functions: `uksort()`,`uasort()`,`uasort()`. It depends on what you need to sort, keys or values.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
// Get this from somewhere (a database or file) - the
// higher the index, the later it will be listed
$indexs = array(
    'Home' => 1,
    'About Us' => 3,
    'Contact Us' => 2
);
$output = array();
// Count in case no indexes are defined
$i = 0;
foreach($views as $view) {
    $output[$view] = isset($indexs[$view]) ? $indexs[$view] : $i++;
}

// Sort array by indexes assigned
asort($output);

// Implode array and use the array key value (not the index value) to output
echo "<ul><li>" . implode('</li><li>', array_keys($output)) . "</li></ul>";
```

But if you are storing weights/index's, you are also better off storing the current pages in your database.

Comment: I think I'll stick the database idea. I've recently converted over to prepared statements and MySQLI so doing things like this have become much easier. Thanks for the code though, it's nice to learn how I could have done it.